# End process & End process tree

Tags: windows, task-manager

What is difference between `End process` and `End process tree` options in task manager? Is it the similar behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

End Process Tree is used to eliminate a process and all the children processes. If you use end process, only one process will be deleted.